# audio.currentTime doesn't work in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, html, audio, internet-explorer-9, html5-audio

I really don't see why the following code seems to work in every browser except IE9:

```
    var audio = $("audio.laser").get(0);
    if (audio != null && audio.canPlayType) {
        audio.pause();
        audio.currentTime = 0;
        audio.play();
    }
```

Strangely, it freezes at "audio.currentTime = 0", saying "currentTime is undefined".

Comment: At what point is this code called? Has the loadedmetadata event already fired at this point?

Comment: Can you post the script this code is being called in?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the loadedmetadata event. I checked and the event is not fired in IE. I discovered that it is because the WAV format I use is not supported. I added a check on the audio duration before playing the sound, like this: "audio.duration >= 0" (quoting the article posted by Travis Powell: "duration - Gets the duration, in seconds, of the current media resource, a NaN value if duration is not available, or Infinity if the media resource is streaming."). It works. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Failure to comply with standards is a web-felony, and IE9 is a repeat offender. Audio looks like it's read-only to me.

Only the things here are supported:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff975061.aspx

Comment: the linked page seems to confirm that currentTime is present. "Gets or sets the current playback position, in seconds."

Comment: Thanks for the link, I noticed I got a "W3CException_DOM_INVALID_STATE" exception, meaning "No media source was selected"... How is that possible? The HTML code is:

Comment: <audio class="laser" src="sounds/laser.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
and I clearly select it...

Answer (score 0):

A couple things to try would be to replace:

`audio.currentTime = 0;`

with

`audio.currentTime = 0.1;`

If that still gives you same error you could try replacing it with:

`audio.load();`

But be aware that load() does not play nicely with the "ended" event. The reason for this escapes me.